# How to create sidebar with menus and few menus having drop down also

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I need to create a side navigation bar with menus along with few menus having drop down. Can anyone help me with that? based on the selection made the view will be shown on the main page using angular ng-view.

Comment: Here you can find a bootstrap sidebar: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

Comment: <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">                                                               <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#section1">P</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">M</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Verify</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">M</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">M</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">C </a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>

Answer (score 0):

Try This One.. This Might Be Helpful To You...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#/">Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#red">Red</a></li>
          <li><a href="#green">Green</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#blue">Blue</a></li> 

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
</script>

<p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED 2 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.navbar-fixed-left {
  width: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
p{
  margin-left:150px;
}
.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;  /* Cancel default li float: left */
  width: 139px;
}

.navbar-fixed-left + .container {
  padding-left: 160px;
}

/* On using dropdown menu (To right shift popuped) */
.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 140px;
}
</style>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#red">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="#green">Green</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#blue">Blue</a></li> 

  </ul>
</div>
<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<div ng-view style="margin-left:150px;"></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
</script>

<p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sachin i want sidebar. But here it is coming in the top.

Comment: Okkk... I will solve your problem With sidebar.... Checkout The Update 2 Code. This Might Be Helpful